# Why must I define variables twice in the Header file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Why must I define variables twice in the header file? What differences are there between these variables?

The first definition is here:

```
@interface MyController: UIViewController
{
    NSInteger selectedIndex;
}
```

The second definition is here:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger selectedIndex;
```

Comment: Please add the language tag to your question too

Comment: In the current version of Xcode, you don't even need the @synthesize. Just define your property and the compiler does the rest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033775/objective-c-multiple-declarations-of-instance-variables-properties

Comment: Just for the record: The second definition is technically not a variable definition, it is a **method definition**, as it defines a getter (`- (NSUInteger)selectedIndex`) and a setter (`- (void)setSelectedIndex:(NSUInteger)selectedIndex`) method. These methods are automatically generated (*"synthesized"*) for you by the compiler and starting with Obj-C 2.0 the compiler will also synthesize an appropriate instance variable for you. Yet a property doesn't have to be backed up by a variable at all, just ipmlement a setter that does nothing and getter returning a const value - no ivar involved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What you're seeing was required in earlier versions of Objective-C,
>   but isn't any more.
>
> In the first versions of Objective-C used by NeXT up until the new
>   runtime was introduced (with Objective-C 2.0 on Mac OS X), all
>   instance variables had to be declared as part of the class's structure
>   in its `@interface`. The reason was that if you subclassed a class,
>   the compiler needed to know the instance variable layout of the class
>   so it could see at what offset to put the subclass's instance
>   variables.
>
> When properties were introduced, synthesized properties had to be
>   "backed" by an instance variable in the class's structure. Therefore
>   you had to declare both an instance variable and the property.
>
> All of the above is no longer true. Newer Objective-C is less fragile
>   in the way it looks up instance variable offsets, which has meant a
>   few changes:
>
> - not all instance variables need to be in the `@interface`. They can now be defined in the `@implementation`: though not in categories due
>     to the possibilities of clashing and other issues.
> - instance variables for synthesized properties can be inferred and created based on the property definition.
> - you can programmatically add instance variables to classes you're creating at runtime (only before you've registered the class as
>     available to the system).
>
> So, to reiterate, you only needed to declare both the instance
>   variable and a synthesized property in older versions of the
>   Objective-C language. What you're seeing is redundant and should not
>   be considered a "best practice".

<sup>[[Source]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11034032/916299)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

As others have pointed out, it is no longer necessary to declare a backing instance variable for a synthesized property in the header.

To make this a bit clearer though: What you're seeing are not two declarations of the same variable, it is one declaration of the variable and one declaration of the *property*.

A property is basically a set of methods (in this case `selectedIndex` and `setSelectedIndex:`) that are typically used to access instance variables. There is a difference between a property and an instance variable. The property's setter/getter could do more than just set the variable, in your example, it could also e.g. update the UI to reflect the change of the selected index or the getter could infer the index from some other variable (in this case, there might be a selection index path), etc.

Synthesizing a property simply frees you of implementing those methods yourself and provides you with default implementations that simply set the variable, but you could also implement `selectedIndex` and `setSelectedIndex:` yourself just like any other method in which case you might either need the instance variable itself or omit it altogether (in case of an inferred property).

Answer (score 3):

In modern runtime you do NOT need to declare them twice. Just use:

In you .h

```
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger selectedIndex;
```

The part between the {} is the declaration of the iVar. And with your @property you declare getter and setters. In modern runtime if you just use the code above you say basicly the same (your iVar is now _selectedIndex).

Comment: In modern runtime you don't need `@synthesize`.

Comment: @David thats right. At the time of writing my code was right. Nowadays you do not even need the `@synthesize` anymore. Corrected my code for the actual situation...